# Kubuntu/Plasma(?) crashes on dual monitor setup

Tags: kubuntu, plasma

I'm using the latest Kubuntu /w Plasma. Usually I have one external monitor, which I connect to my laptop. Everything worked sort of fine (except of few restarts needed to get both displays working per try), but since yesterday, the second display doesn't want to load at all.
I've tried several things (which tended to work before):

1. Restarted the laptop and plugged off anything that was connected to the laptop. Waited everything to load and connected the monitor through a VGA port. That didn't work. (I will post a picture below with the result)
2. Did the same as *1.* but I left the monitor plugged in. Both displays showed the login screen, but I couldn't login because every time I entered the password the loading screen appeared and when it was complete it "redirected" me to the login screen. An infinite loop.

None of the ways worked, though they used to work.

This is the screenshot. I've marked with redlines where it looks really disturbing. It's like the screen was sliced in to pieces. And the mouse pointer can only move vertically only at the left edge of the screen.
[image]

> Note: None of this is clickable.

When I disconnect the external display everything goes back to normal. (this time `Konsole` crashed, but I relaunched it successfully)

[image][image]

Comment: I installed Kubuntu 15.04 recently on a laptop and am experiencing the same issue. Plasma (plasmashell,krunner) die on external monitor connect/disconnect/lid open/close. The screen appears dislocated, just as your pic does. Just about to downgrade kde actually...

Comment: I didn't find any solution on this. Can you report back if downgrading helps?

Comment: Upgrading to qt5.5 is supposed to be the fix, but despite using the .run script or compiling from source, dpkg --list | grep qt still shows 5.4 as installed. Exceedingly frustrating.